# Knowing that $a_m = 2a_{m - 1}(a_{m - 1} + 1)$, find $n$ such that $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_{m - 1}^2 + a_m^2 + n^2$ is a square number.

Tags: number-theory, induction

> Knowing that $$\large a_0 \in \mathbb Z \mid a_m = 2a_{m - 1}(a_{m - 1} + 1), \forall m \in \mathbb Z^+$$, find $n$ such that $$\large a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_{m - 1}^2 + a_m^2 + n^2$$ is a square number for $\forall m \in \mathbb Z^+$.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. The solution might include mathematical induction and I don't know about it.

Comment: I’m gonna guess if such an $n$ exists, it is equal to $2a_0+1.$

Comment: @Thomas That would work all right for $m=1$. But there is obviously no constant that would be good for all $m$ at once (which is what the question seems to be asking).

Comment: I'm quite sure the first step would be to write $2a_m + 1 = (2a_{m-1}+1)^2$, then it follows that: $2a_m + 1 = (2a_0+1)^{2m}$. Then we can convert the sum to the function of $a_0, m, n$ only.

Comment: Thus @ThomasAndrews's guess is not correct, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use $~a_k^2=\frac{1}{2}a_{k+1}-a_k~$ to simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is not possible:
Assume there are $b_m\ge0$ with
$$a_1^2+\cdots +a_m^2+n^2=b_m^2.$$
For example, if $a_0=1$, we find $a_1=4$, so
$$b_1^2=16+n^2.$$
Then $16=b_1^2-n^2=(b_1+n)(b_1-n)$, where both factirs have same, hence even, parity. This allows only $b_1+n=8$, $b_1-n=2$, so necessarily $n=3$, $b_1=5$.
But $a_2=2a_1(a_1+1)=40$, and we'd need
$$b_2^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+n^2=1625,$$
which is not a square.

Comment: I imagine you are using the same $n$ for both cases $m=1$ and $m=2$. But I think the question means for each $m$, there exists a number $n_m$, rather than the existence of a universal $n$.

Comment: @SiXUlm That's definitely not how I read the problem statement, though the order of natural language quantifiers where one is placed before and the other behind the statement is always ambiguous. And "some expression $+n^2$ is  a square" would just boild down to the triviality "some expression is odd or a multiple of $4$"

Answer (score -1):

Above equation shown below:

$$\large a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_{m - 1}^2 + a_m^2 + n^2=p^2 \tag{1}$$

Equation $(1)$ has numerical solution:

For, $m=3$ and $a_1=1$ we get:

$$(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,4,40)$$

And, $(n,p)=(8,41)$

Hence,

$$1^2+4^2+40^2+8^2=41^2$$

Comment: "find n such that $a_1^2+\cdots+a_m^2+n^2$ is a square number for all $m\in \mathbb{Z+}$." For m=4 you have $a_1^2+\cdots+a_4^2+8^2$ is not a square number.